# NSFetchedResultsController Sections

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I set up an NSFetchedResultsController as follows:

```
self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:self.contactsDatabase.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"nameInitial" cacheName:nil];
```

The first time I run my app, the NSFetchedResultsController delegate below is called.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSLog([[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] description]);

    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Number of Sections = %i", [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count]]);

    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}
```

The fetch request seems to work fine, as I get a full NSLog of the array description.

However the method returns number of sections = 0, so I get a blank table view.

When I close the app, and then run it for a second time, it works properly.

Any ideas?

Comment: At what time in the execution are you running this? Maybe the NSFetchedResultsController is not ready yet

Comment: viewDidLoad calls a method to set up the NSFetchedResultsController. It works fine if I don't use sections, so it seems it's ready...

Comment: Do you have a first sort descriptor for the key `nameInitial`, as required when using `sectionNameKeyPath`? - Can you show the NSLog() output of `[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]` and `[self.fetchedResultsController sections]`?

Comment: I do, have tried using name and nameInitial, no effect. I showed some of the nslog data for nsfetchedresultscontroller in this link, sorry can give any more right now, don't have access to my laptop for now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492052/what-is-causing-the-difference-in-this-core-data-output